# Cannot split string by multiple characters in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Hi I'm trying to split strings by ".\n\n" or ". \n\n" instead of "\n\n".
But when I tried the following code, the string was splitted by "\n\n":

```
import re    
text = 'Thanks.\n\n This is the first time. \n\n Yes \n\n indeed.'
re.split('. \n\n|.\n\n', text)
```

Here's the result:

```
['Thanks', ' This is the first time', ' Ye', ' indeed.']
```

What I want to get is

```
['Thanks', ' This is the first time', 'Yes \n\n indeed.']
```

In addition, could I split strings by

```
"?|!|." + "\n\n"?
```

Comment: Escape the `.` char in the regex pattern to match it as a literal char.

Comment: dot is a wildcard in regex try `re.split('\. \n\n|\.\n\n', text)`